# EF: EnsureLoadedForContext method

Tags: entity-framework

I am reading EF's source code and found this method below. According to the method name, it make sure that the dbcontext is loaded. When I test this with EF Codefirst sample, this method is added the current assembly (my sample console) to "_knownAssemblies"..

I don't see any code of loading the assembly. And I don't see any code that checks whether the assembly is loaded or not.

Is that the naming issue or Did I miss out something? Thanks in advance.

```
 public virtual void EnsureLoadedForContext(Type contextType)
        {
            DebugCheck.NotNull(contextType);
            Debug.Assert(typeof(DbContext).IsAssignableFrom(contextType));

            var contextAssembly = contextType.Assembly;

            if (contextType == typeof(DbContext)
                || _knownAssemblies.ContainsKey(contextAssembly))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (_configurationOverrides.IsValueCreated)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    if (_configurationOverrides.Value.Count != 0)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!ConfigurationSet)
            {
                var foundConfigurationType =
                    _loader.TryLoadFromConfig(AppConfig.DefaultInstance) ??
                    _finder.TryFindConfigurationType(contextType);

                if (foundConfigurationType != null)
                {
                    SetConfigurationType(foundConfigurationType);
                }
            }
            else if (!contextAssembly.IsDynamic // Don't throw for proxy contexts created in dynamic assemblies
                     && !_loader.AppConfigContainsDbConfigurationType(AppConfig.DefaultInstance))
            {
                var foundType = _finder.TryFindConfigurationType(contextType);
                if (foundType != null)
                {
                    if (_configuration.Value.Owner.GetType() == typeof(DbConfiguration))
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(Strings.ConfigurationNotDiscovered(foundType.Name));
                    }
                    if (foundType != _configuration.Value.Owner.GetType())
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(
                            Strings.SetConfigurationNotDiscovered(_configuration.Value.Owner.GetType().Name, contextType.Name));
                    }
                }
            }

            _knownAssemblies.TryAdd(contextAssembly, null);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `EnsureLoadedForContext` does not load the context but loads a configuration **for** the context type passed to the method. When you look at the name of the method with the type name on which the method is created (`DbConfigurationManager.EnsureLoadedForContext`) it is much more clear that the method is related to loading a configuration rather than loading a context. Finally you can look at a comment to one of the [bugs](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/671) which reads:

> EnsureLoadedForContext is called from various places as soon as a context type is known to ensure that the correct DbConfiguration is found.

Comment: Yes. "DbConfigurationManager.EnsureLoadedForContext)" makes more sense to me now.. Thanks